# Django Celery Changes Not Applied

Tags: python, django, windows, redis, celery

My django-celery code cannot reload, which I concluded after seeing an error that was supposedly resolved. Can anyone tell me how to properly restart my Celery server, or is the problem still existent?

Running on Windows 10, by the way.

*file structure*

```sh
|-- manage.py
|-- nttracker\
    |-- celery.py
    |-- tasks.py
    |-- settings.py
```

I have not yet added any separate configuration files yet.

**nttracker/celery.py**

```py
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'nttracker.settings')
postgres_broker = 'sqla+postgresql://user:pass@host/name'

app = Celery('nttracker', broker='amqp://', backend='rpc://', include=['nttracker.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-10-seconds': {
        'task': 'nttracker.tasks.add',
        'schedule': 10.0,
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**nttracker/tasks.py**

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import

import django
django.setup()

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print(x + y)
```

**nttracker/settings.py**

```py
# Celery Configuration Options
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "valid/timezone"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'

# celery setting.
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'default'

# django setting.
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'my_cache_table',
    }
}
```

**terminal one output** (`celery -A nttracker worker --pool=solo -l INFO`)

```sh
[2021-06-04 20:03:54,409: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: nttracker.tasks.add[4f9e0e15-82de-4cdb-be84-d3690ebe142e]
[2021-06-04 20:03:54,411: WARNING/MainProcess] 32
[2021-06-04 20:03:54,494: INFO/MainProcess] Task nttracker.tasks.add[4f9e0e15-82de-4cdb-be84-d3690ebe142e] succeeded in 0.09399999999732245s: 
None
[2021-06-04 20:04:04,451: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: nttracker.tasks.add[da9c8999-3937-44fd-8d4b-15ff83977a4b]
[2021-06-04 20:04:04,452: WARNING/MainProcess] 32
[2021-06-04 20:04:04,529: INFO/MainProcess] Task nttracker.tasks.add[da9c8999-3937-44fd-8d4b-15ff83977a4b] succeeded in 0.07800000000861473s: 
None
[2021-06-04 20:04:14,497: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: nttracker.tasks.add[c82b5099-e1dd-4f7b-a068-8041268571d1]
[2021-06-04 20:04:14,498: WARNING/MainProcess] 32
[2021-06-04 20:04:14,568: INFO/MainProcess] Task nttracker.tasks.add[c82b5099-e1dd-4f7b-a068-8041268571d1] succeeded in 0.0629999999946449s: None
[2021-06-04 20:04:23,187: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[16, 16], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (83b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xxxx\onedrive\desktop\github_new\nttracker\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 555, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'tasks.add'
[2021-06-04 20:04:24,544: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: nttracker.tasks.add[66f050ac-b17d-4a7c-9bc6-564cc1d84ae1]
[2021-06-04 20:04:24,545: WARNING/MainProcess] 32
[2021-06-04 20:04:24,620: INFO/MainProcess] Task nttracker.tasks.add[66f050ac-b17d-4a7c-9bc6-564cc1d84ae1] succeeded in 0.07799999999406282s: 
None
```

**terminal two output** (`celery -A nttracker beat -S django`)

```sh
celery beat v5.0.5 (singularity) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2021-06-04 19:58:21
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler      

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
```

I'd like to stress the point that, in a 30-second interval, 32 was printed trice (from `add(16, 16)` but there will also be one `tasks.add error`.

I've tried to restart my redis server and celery's worker and beat, but the initial import error was still not resolved.

Can anyone please help? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

import your task project settings.py file

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
   "import task here"
)
```

Comment: What should "import task here" be? I added `'nttracker.tasks'` but the error persists